# PySpark: No such file or directory error when creating a SparkContext on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed Spark sucessfully and am able to launch Spark from my terminal through "spark-shell" command, but i can't get instantiate a SparkContext from jupyter notebook and am getting this error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Here is my code in the jupyter notebook:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
```

Here is my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/NAME/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark'
export SPARK_HOME='/usr/local/spark'
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Is the dir export SPARK_HOME='/usr/local/spark'  located where you have installed jupyter, please check

Comment: @KrazyGautam no, my jupyter is installed in: /Users/NAME/anaconda2/bin/jupyter

Comment: @KrazyGautam Hey, i resolved it by typing PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark in the command line. This article helped: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/apache-spark-python. After that, there actually isn't a need to create a Spark Context again